# PHP global $db call in function

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
function beginProcess(){
    global $db; 
    $sql = "SELECT last_batch from ".TABLE_STATUS.";";            
    $lastBatch = $db->Execute($sql);
    $lastBatch=(int)$lastBatch->fields['last_batch'];
    echo "<BR/>Last Batch = ".$lastBatch;

    if ($lastBatch >=1 && $lastBatch <=3 ){
        $batch = $lastBatch +1;
    }else{
        $batch = 1;
    }
        processBatch($batch);
}
```

Will $db be available to the processBatch function so I can use db functionality or do I have to define it again in processBatch() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will not be. You won't be able to access `$db` inside the `processBatch()` function because it is outside the scope of the function -- that means PHP can only see the variables defined inside the function. You *could* use the `global` keyword (as you're currently doing with the `beginProcess()` function) to let PHP know that the variable is outside the function's scope -- and instruct it to import the variable into the function scope.

It's generally considered bad practice to use `global` variables in your code, and I think a better course of action would be to pass the `$db` into the function as a function parameter:

```
function processBatch($db, $batch){
    // $db is now available inside the function
    // more code ...
}
```

That way, your code will be cleaner and more maintainable. Consult the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more information on variable scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to use `global keyword` in `progressBatch function` like,

```
function processBatch($batch){
   global $db;
   // your remaining code
}
```

Read [Variables Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

**Alternatively** you have to pass `$db` in `processBatch function` like,

```
function processBatch($batch,$db){
   // $db available now
   // your remaining code
}
```

And Call it like,

```
processBatch($batch,$db);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to redefine it in every function that uses it: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

If you don't want that, you can use

```
$GLOBALS['db']
```

instead of

```
global $db;
$db
```

which is identical.

Comment: I hate downvotes without explanation. Such cowardice!

Comment: I countered the downvote, as I see no reason that your answer should have received it. The other answers are expressed more clearly, but yours is factually correct also.